# REST WCF service does not return a response

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, rest

I have created a rest wcf service. The service itself is working fine. From localhost browse I can call all functions. Below is the contract and the function.

The problem is that the service does not return response when I try to save using db.savechanges(). If I comment out that line the JSON response is returned.

Am I doing something wrong in my code?

```
 [DataContract]
     public class RouteObject{
     public List<DetailRouteInfo>routeDetail {get; set;} /// this is Entity Model Class; 
    }
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate="GRDI?route={route}&cloc={cloc}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        RouteObject GRDI(string route,string cLoc);

public RouteObject GRDI(string route, string cLoc) { 

        MapApiClient mClient = new MapApiClient();
        Response mData= new Response();
        var coord=route.Split('|');
        RouteObject rObject = new RouteObject();
        rObject.routeDetail = new List<DriverRouteInfo>(); ;
        //this variable needs to updated later
        //List<string> dummyCoord= new List<string>();
        List<Task> wtask = new List<Task>();
        mClient.getRouteData(coord.ToList(), (x) =>
            {
                mData = x;
            },
            (y) => 
            {
                wtask.Add(y);
            }
            );

        if (wtask != null)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(wtask.ToArray());
            wtask.Clear();
        }
        DriverRouteInfo droute=null;

// DO SOME MANIPULATION WITH THE DROUTE //
// THEN ADD LIST OF DROUTE INTO ROUTOBJECT.DETAILROUTE //

        try 
        {
            using (var db = new F2PDatabaseEntities())
            {
                UserInfo userinfo = db.UserInfoes.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == 1);
                //userinfo.DriverRouteInfoes = listRoute;
                foreach(var dr in rObject.routeDetail){
                    userinfo.DriverRouteInfoes.Add(dr);
                }
               db.SaveChanges();
                return rObject;

            }
            var check = droute.RouteId;


        }

        catch(SqlException ex) {
            throw new FaultException(ex.Message); ;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

http://zamd.net/2008/07/08/error-handling-with-webhttpbinding-for-ajaxjson/

Another tips:

- Put [DataMember] attribute over the

  ```
  public List<DetailRouteInfo>routeDetail {get; set;}
  ```

  property. And make sure that DetailRouteInfo class has got [DataContract]  attribute.
- Do not throw exception to client. It causes undesirable results if you can't handle correctly. Build a base response object, which includes a property for returning a response code or message, and, inherit your RouteObject class from this base class.